# Make PHP html_erros link active in xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug, directive

On PHP when the `html_errors` directive is set to `On` it displays handy links to the manual of the offending function such as:

> Warning: require_once(offending_file.php)
>   [[function.require-once]](http://php.net/manual/function.require-once): failed to open stream: ...

However, once xdebug is turned on the  tag is passed verbose and you end up with something like:

> Warning: require_once(offending_file.php) [http://php.net/manual/function.require-once'>function.require-once]: failed to open stream: ...

How can I enable those links again when using xdebug? I looked over the xdebug directives and I couldn't find the one.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't reproduce your behaviour, the setting related to that is xdebug.manual_url.

In any case, here is my configuration so you can test it.

```
    zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php5.5/lib/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.auto_trace="1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/var/log/xdebug"
xdebug.trace_output_name="trace.%s_%t"
xdebug.trace_format="0"
xdebug.trace_options="1"
xdebug.collect_assignments="1"
xdebug.collect_includes="1"
xdebug.collect_params="4"
xdebug.collect_return="0"
xdebug.collect_vars="1"
xdebug.default_enable="1"
xdebug.extended_info="1"
xdebug.manual_url="http://www.php.net"
xdebug.max_nesting_level="100"
xdebug.show_exception_trace="1"
xdebug.show_local_vars="1"
xdebug.show_mem_delta="1"
xdebug.dump.COOKIE=false
xdebug.dump.ENV=false
xdebug.dump.FILES=false
xdebug.dump.GET="NULL"
xdebug.dump.POST="NULL"
xdebug.dump.REQUEST="NULL"
xdebug.dump.SERVER="NULL"
xdebug.dump.SESSION="NULL"
xdebug.dump_globals="1"
xdebug.dump_once="1"
xdebug.dump_undefined="1"
xdebug.pror_enable="0"
xdebug.profiler_enable="1"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/log/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name="%s_%t"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger="0"
xdebug.profiler_append="0"
xdebug.profiler_aggregate="0"
xdebug.remote_enable="On"
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.remote_autostart="0"
xdebug.remote_log=""
xdebug.idekey=""
xdebug.var_display_max_data="16384"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth="10"
xdebug.var_display_max_children="512"
xdebug.max_nesting_level="100"
xdebug.overload_var_dump="1"
xdebug.scream="1"
xdebug.cli_color="1"
xdebug.coverage_enable="1"
```